# Using arrow keys to rotate an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm trying to rotate an object Cannon when pressing the horizontal arrow keys. My C# script looks like this; but sadly I get parsing error and "Unexpecting symbol '{'" in Unity :(

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float HorizontalKeys;
public Transform Cannon;

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetAxis("HorizontalKeys")){
        if(Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalKeys" == -1){
            Cannon.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log("Test");
        }if(Input.GetKey ("HorizontalKeys" == 1){
            Cannon.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _"if someone know some tuts, works, examples"_ - _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 0):

Finish your if statements with an enclosing ")"

```
if(Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalKeys" == -1)) {

}
```